# Why CSS Isolation in Blazor is not working?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I read in many tutorials :

- Just create a file containing the same filename of the page plus .css - Example: for Orders.razor, create a file Orders.razor.css
- Add your style on the css file and have fun

Ok, but this is not working. So, what is the correct approach ? To reproduce:

- Create a new solution, client side
- Wait for the solution being created and the sample boilerplate (counter, fetchdata, etc)
- On the pages folder, create a file"Index.razor.css"
- On the created file, add: h1 { color : red }
- Execute the solution

Expected result: Hello, world! in red

Received: Hello, world! in black

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
Welcome to your new app.
<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
```

**Index.razor.css**

```
h1 {
   color: red
}
```

Comment: did you try to Clear the browser cache x) also what version of .net are you using

Comment: Yes...In fact wasn't even necessary to clear the cache...I just created a new app to illustrate the issue and this failed on the 1st execution. But yes, even if I clear the cache, this happens. Using 4.8.04084

Comment: Using 4.8? 4.8 of what? Are you sure you are looking in the correct place? Click in the `.csproj` file and tell us what is inside `TargetFramework`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `.razor.css` files to work, you need to be using .net5

Take a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and see if you didn't miss any step

Comment: I made an attempt before using ::deep ...just forgot to mention it. No, it's not working as well.

Comment: Thanks !!! Yes, that's was the problem: Not using .net5 !

Comment: I'm using .net6.0 and this is not working.